# Problem about max and min values of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let a $function$ be continuous on a closed bounded region $R$, and let it be analytic and not constant throughout the interior of R. Assuming that $f(z) \neq 0$ anywhere in R. Prove that $|f(z)|$ has minimum value m in R which occurs on the boundary of R and never in the interior. Do this by applying by applying the corresponding result for maximum values (Sec. 59) to the function $g(z)=1/f(z)$

Approach we have two results

Theorem: If a function $f$ is analytic and not constant in a given domain D, then $|f(z)|$ has no maximum value in $D$. That is, there is no point $z_0$ in the domain such that $|f(z)| \leq |f(z_0)|$ for all points $z$ in it.

Corollary: Suppose that a function f is continuous on a closed bounded region $R$ and that it is analytic and not constant in the interior of $R$. Then the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ in $R$, which is always reached, occurs somewhere on the boundary of $R$ and never in the interior

Approach:

If we consider $|g(z)|$, it's minimum is found at the max value of $|f(z)|$ by the corollary. How does that tell us we can find a minimum value on R for $f(z)$?

Maybe we would argue that $1/f(z)$ is analytic and not constant in R, so its max value is on a boundary point. This implies that the min value $f(z)$
 is on a boundary point. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\frac{1}{f(z)}$. It is clearly analytic in the region (since $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$ in the region and $f$ is analytic) and not constant (since $f(z)$ is not constant). Now apply the maximum modulus principle to $\frac{1}{f(z)}$. Maximum of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ will be the minimum of $f(z)$.